# How to show multiple items with the same information?

Tags: c++

I'm coding a program that can show the information from a list of students. I'm wondering how can I make the program to print out all the students who share the same information. For example: There are two students who both live London and when I type in 'London' the program only prints out the first student it finds in the list. Here's my current code:

```
void Person_list::findAddr()
{
    Person *s;
    string addr;
    string temp_addr;
    s = head;
    cout << "Please enter student's address: ";
    getline(cin, addr);
    while ((s!=NULL) && (s-> Get_addr() != addr))
    {
        s = s -> next;
    }

    if (s != NULL)
    {
        s -> Show();
    }

    if (s == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Cant find. \n" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Loop over *all* structures in the list, and use an `if` statement in the loop to see if the structure matches your condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is the condition of your while loop:

> `while ((s!=NULL) && (s-> Get_addr() != addr))`

It says: as long as s is not null and the address is not the one you are looking for, look at the next student.

At your first finding the loop terminates, so that subsequent possible hits are never reached.

You can do it like this instead:

```
while (s != nullptr) {
    if (s-> Get_addr() == addr) {
        s -> Show();
    }
    s = s -> next;
}
```

It iterates over all students and only prints them if their address matches.

Comment: Notice how I replaced your `NULL` with the `nullptr` keyword which is strongly preferred over the NULL macro since C++11, see section "nullptr" in this [Cprogramming article](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-nullptr-strongly-typed-enum-class.html)